# How to use teamviewer if the remote computer has restarted?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have a computer that I use in my work. I've installed `TeamViewer` and I log into it from my home using my laptop. Sometimes the computer restarts for some reason and I won't be able to connect to from home. So I am thinking of making a program that will store the information (partner and password) in a text file and store it in my `dropbox` folder so I can see it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Would be nice to say what OS you are using... Linux? Windows? Mac?

Comment: Why don't you open a TeamViewer account and get the machines to log into it automatically? This was designed for precisely your situation. The **Computers & Contacts** window will give immediate access to any other machines linked to the same account as soon as they come on-line and with no further validation.

Comment: @Jakke I am using Windows. Thanks to you too for your replies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set teamviewer up for unattended access. This installs a Windows Service so you can access the computer without being logged in / starting Teamviewer. You can see the exact instructions on teamviewer.com (http://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/first-steps-unattended-access-en.pdf)

In short, if you open the Teamviewer window, there's a small box for a password for unattended access on the bottom left side. When you fill in the password (Personal Password), you will set up your unattended access.

You can also create a teamviewer account, log in from the application and add the computer to your list. Once you're logged in on another computer, simply double-click the computer from the list and you'll start a remote session.

Again, more info and detailed information on http://www.teamviewer.com

Comment: I've did that but for some reason I still get the "A connection could not be established. Teamviewer not running on partner". It's working if I log on the server. using Windows Server 2012 and TeamViewer 11.

Comment: You're giving yourself the answer. Teamviewer is working but something in the connection is blocking you. Check your firewall or other intrusion detection system and your basic network setup.